# Cannot run XAMARIN UI TEST on xamarin.forms, error System.Exception

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uitest

I want ton run Xamarin UI test, but when i run the test i have this error :

```
System.Exception : 'The running adb server is incompatible with the Android SDK version in use by UITest: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

my start command-line : 
`return ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile("/Users/Jerem/source/repos/App4/App4/App4.Android/bin/Debug/com.companyname.App4-Signed.apk").StartApp();`

Thanks for our helping

Comment: What android SDK are u using??

Comment: @Woj I use SDK 27

Comment: What about Xamarin.UITest?

Comment: Last version, 2.25.. 
for the nunit package, I did not touch it and I let the basic ones

Comment: I noticed that I also had this: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1201 Project App4.Android is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) / win-x86. Project App4.Android supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1) UITest1 C:\Users\Jerem\source\repos\App4\UITest1\UITest1.csproj 1

Comment: and this when i want run test : [10/09/2018 13:13:44 Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:03,240636) ==========
[10/09/2018 13:15:47 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[10/09/2018 13:15:48 Warning] L'exécuteur de tests ayant l'URI 'executor://nunittestexecutor/' est introuvable. Vérifiez que l'exécuteur de tests est installé et qu'il prend en charge le runtime .NET version  .
[10/09/2018 13:15:48 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00,8840368) ==========

Comment: I would *assume* you have multiple android sdks installed on your PC

Comment: i don't know, where i can find this ?

Comment: i find platform-tools.old****, i delete this

Comment: I find the problem, I had several SDK, thank you very much!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have the same error, check in our sdk directory if you have platform-tools and platform-tools.oldxxxx, delete old ! Just work after

Comment: I had to revert to the .old and remove the newer version.

Answer (score 11):

Y Nakamura's answer moved me in the right direction but it still took me a long time to solve because I wasn't sure exactly what I was trying to solve. I'm going to expand on the answer here in case others run into the same problems that I did.

As mentioned, the problem seems to be caused by the files (not sure if it's adb.exe or other files) inside of platform-tools not being supported by Xamarin.UITest. **platform-tools** can be found in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk**

I had **platform-tools** folder, plus two additional folders with **old12341234** suffixes (the numbers didn't make any sense to me).

To figure out which version of adb.exe is in each folder:

1. Open one of the folders
2. Hold shift and right-click in the windows explorer window to see the **Open PowerShell window here** option
3. In PowerShell, run the command `./adb.exe version` to see the version number you are running
   [image: Powershell adb version]

In my case, the version that was too new was **1.0.40**. I found a folder that had **1.0.39**. I renamed the **platform-tools** folder that was too new to **platform-toolsTooNew**. I then renamed the folder that contained adb.exe v 1.0.39 to **platform-tools**, then restarted Visual Studio.

After doing all of that, my automated tests once-again worked!

### Update November 2020

I was able to run with a newer version of ADB, but I had to delete the **old** folder from my **android-sdk** folder. I am using:

- ADB version 1.0.41
- Visual Studio 16.6.5
- Xamarin 16.6.000.1064
- Xamarin.Android SDK 10.3.1.4

I'll keep my original post above in case it helps others.

Comment: The versions are actually 1.0.40 and 1.0.39 rather than 1.40 and 1.39.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: Wish Xamarin.UITools would tell us which one it ACTUALLY wanted

Answer (score 6):

*Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.0 (40)* is too new. Try restoring *27.0.1 (39)*. Open folder `%ANDROID_HOME%`. If the folders `platform-tools` and `platform-tools.oldxxxx` appears, rename them to restore old version.